# Linux read systemcall does not read from file

Tags: c++, linux, file

I have a C++ program that opens a file with O_DIRECT flag and writes a buffer of size 100 Mb to a file with write system call. The program defines a block size equal to 512 and does as below:

```
const int BLKSZ = 512;
const int MAXBUFSIZE = 100000000;

char buf[MAXBUFSIZE];// store data in this buffer and write it to file

size_t len;// number of bytes of buf is full

int fd = open(fName.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_DIRECT , mode);

#ifdef DIRECTIO
        This->remNAligNum = len % BLKSZ;
        if(This->remNAligNum)
        {
            This->remNAlig = ((char *)buf + len);
            len -= This->remNAligNum;
        }
        else
            This->remNAlig = NULL;

#endif

char *buffOffset = (char *)buf;
int buffRem = len;
wr = 0;
while(1){
    buffOffset += wr;
    buffRem -= wr;
    if(!buffRem)
    break;
    wr = write(fd, buffOffset, buffRem));   
    usleep(5);
}
```

This code writes data to file successfully but in below code read system call can not read any data from file and returns -1.

```
const int BLKSZ = 512;
const int MAXBUFSIZE = 100000000;

char buf[MAXBUFSIZE];
char tmpbuf[BLKSZ];

int fd = open(fName.c_str(), O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT, mode);
int ret2 = read(fd, tmpbuf, BLKSZ);
```

Comment: read() returned -1 what is the errno ?

Comment: Have you checked whether the `open()` succeeded? If not, what was the return code? What was the value of `errno` after the `read()` call returned -1?

Comment: `len` is never initialized.

Comment: @ philant, -1 means Interrupt when reading from file descriptor.

Comment: @ Galik, I initialized it in the main code.

Comment: If `read()` returns `-1` then try printing: `std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';`

Comment: @MSH: -1 could mean that, or any number of other things too. You need to give the value of `errno`, preferably in string form as @Galik suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Call close(fd) when you write complete(between while () and open (read only)).

Answer (score 0):

That's solved! The problem is access permission of file.